# Enviar datos en petición POST usando Kotlin

Tags: android, post, http, kotlin

tengo una duda, como puedo mandar datos desde una petición http en kotlin sin utilizar ninguna librería.
Este es mi código:

```
val obj = URL(url)
    doAsync {
        with(obj.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection) {
            requestMethod = "POST"
            println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : $url")
            println("Response Code : $responseCode")

            BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use {
                val response = StringBuffer()

                var inputLine = it.readLine()
                while (inputLine != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine)
                    inputLine = it.readLine()
                }
                println("RESPONSE::: $response")
            }
        }
    }
```

en el servidor hay un archivo PHP esperando 2 datos

```
$_POST['data1'];

$_POST['data2'];
```

De antemano, muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Sergio ¿Cual es el problema que se presenta? , Agrega el error mostrado en el LogCat.

Comment: No muestra ningún error, hace la petición correctamente, pero no conozco la sintaxis para añadir datos que un archivo PHP va a recibir como POST en el servidor

Comment: He agregado una repuesta adecuando los valores que deseas enviar mediante una petición POST @SergioGracía

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Petición Post en Kotlin.

Veo que usas [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) en lugar de un `AsyncTask` lo cual es buena opción para evitar `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

De acuerdo a los valores que recibirá tu pagina que son:

```
$_POST['data1'];
$_POST['data2'];
```

Puedes realizar un método el cual recibirá los valores de `data1` y `data2` :

```
fun sendPost(data1:String, data2:String) {
    
    //Define url para realizar peticion POST.
    var urlPost = "<Define url que acepta petición POST>";

    //Concatena y codifica parámetros.
    var reqParam = URLEncoder.encode("data1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(data1, "UTF-8") 
    reqParam += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("data2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(data2, "UTF-8")

    val mURL = URL(urlPost)

    with(mURL.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection) {
        //Define metodo
        requestMethod = "POST"

        val wr = OutputStreamWriter(getOutputStream());
        wr.write(reqParam);
        wr.flush();

        println(requestMethod + "URL : $url")
        println(requestMethod + "Response Code : $responseCode")

        BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use {
            val response = StringBuffer()

            var inputLine = it.readLine()
            while (inputLine != null) {
                response.append(inputLine)
                inputLine = it.readLine()
            }
            it.close()
            //imprime respuesta.
            println("POST Response : $response")
            
        }
    }
}
```

y llamar el método `sendPost()` enviando los valores de `data1` y `data2`, esto dentro de `doAsync`.

Ejemplo:

```
doAsync {

    sendPost("Soy data1!", "Soy data2!")

}
```

Comment: Excelente! me funcionó de maravilla! muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Que bien @SergioGarcía , recuerdo siempre aportar datos a tu pregunta de esta forma será más fácil para la comunidad apoyarte, un saludo!